# Java Swing - Show multiple panels

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I'm using the Java Swing UI Designer in IntelliJ :( I designed something in the designer using multiple panels and spacers with 1 parent panel. When I add the main panel, the first one inside it shows, but the others don't.

Frame structure:

- Panel1

  - GradientPanel

    - Panel
    - Spacers

What I designed
[image: What I designed]

What I get
[image: What I get when I run it]

```
import keeptoo.KGradientPanel;

import javax.swing.*;

public class LogIn extends JFrame{
private KGradientPanel KGradientPanel1; //Automatically added by the designer
private JPanel panel1; //Automatically added by the designer

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("CarbonTec Dashboard");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(1800,1000);
    frame.setContentPane(new LogIn().panel1);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("Icon.png");
    frame.setIconImage(imageIcon.getImage());
}
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: Setting the `JFrame` visible via `setVisible(true)` should be done as the last step after you added all your components and set up your GUI. Also, don't `extends JFrame` if you don't actually want to change the frame functionality.

Comment: (1-) @Tom6468 *The invention Java Swing is the worst thing* - don't blame the tool, blame the carpenter. Swing is very easy to use. The code you posted tells us nothing. It doesn't even show you adding the gradient panel to the frame or the child panels to the gradient panel.  Also, using the UI designer is not recommended. You spend your time learning the designer and not learning Swing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to know that your class is a JFrame, but in the main method you create a new JFrame.

Better would be to have a class Program that has the main method. In this main method you make a new instance of LogIn.

The Program class can look like this:

```
public class MainProgram {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LogIn logIn = new LogIn();
  }
}
```

The LogIn class should then look like this:

```
    import keeptoo.KGradientPanel;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class LogIn extends JFrame{
    private KGradientPanel KGradientPanel1 = new KGradientPanel(); //Automatically added by the designer
    private JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(); //Automatically added by the designer
    

    // This is the constructor.
    public LogIn {
    
        setTitle("CarbonTec Dashboard");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(1800,1000);
        setContentPane(panel1);
    
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("Icon.png");
        setIconImage(imageIcon.getImage());

        // Here you can add the gradient panel to panel1.
        panel1.add(KGradientPanel1); // The name should be written in lower case.
       
        setVisible(true);
    }
```

But I don't know why you need the panel1, you could add the KGradientPanel directly.

Comment: I did all that, but now it's just all white. IntelliJ says that the JPanel and KGradientPanel are overwritten by generated code, probably the built-in designer. When I remove that part, it's back to where it was before

Comment: Then it looks like your login is the whole window. Then to add a panel to this frame you have to use the method `getContentPane().add(Component c)`. I don't know which panel is the one on the right (black).

Comment: This is the structure in the designer: https://imgur.com/a/F396YY1
The gray panel is inside the gradientpanel. The thing is that it doesn't show up in the java class

Comment: Ok, then it looks like your panel1 is your main panel. So you have to give this panel a layout to be able to position elements on it.  If you don't specify a layout, then it's the FlowLayout, which is how the elements are lined up. Thus, the white/black panel is next to the GradientPanel.

Either replace the panel1 with the GradientPanel so that it is in the background. Then you have to give the GradientPanel a layout to place the white/black on it.

If you can't replace the panel1, you need to give the GradientPanel a layout and then add the white/black panel on top of it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it just doesn't work. The invention Java Swing is the worst thing that happened to this world. Im going to uninstall it, otherwhise I might punch my monitor.

Comment: A hint from me, do not use a designer but try to program it yourself. It is much more relaxed, then you are completely variable.

Comment: And please vote this answer.